# Transferring 16gb microSD to 64gb

Tags: raspbian, sd-card, linux, noobs, memory

I made a backup of the 16gb microSD card (installed with NOOBS) for a Raspberry Pi 3 and saved it to my Mac using:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/disk2 of=~/Desktop/raspberrypi.dmg
```

Then, I took a 64gb microSD card, formatted it to exFAT using the SDFormatter tool (while turning Logical Address Adjustment on), and formatted it to FAT32 and unmounted it using:

```
sudo diskutil eraseDisk FAT32 RASPBIAN MBRFormat /dev/disk2

diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk2
```

Now I got hasty and accidentally ran the same dd command as above (I should have ran `sudo dd if=~/Desktop/raspberrypi.dmg of=/dev/disk2`). This copied the blank 64gb microSD to the raspberrypi.dmg file until my Mac ran out of memory. So now the .dmg file is corrupted.

Since I created the first copy of the image, I made some changes to the 16gb microSD card and completely filled up its memory. I cloned its image to my Mac again and followed the same process to transfer it to my 64gb card. The start screen still shows up and I can enter recovery mode by pressing shift on startup. However, if I let it go on its own it brings me to a blank screen with only a blinking underscore. Any ideas of how to fix this?

Comment: Most of this question is just a bad luck story, and irrelevant. (You should in any event use `rdisk2` instead of `disk2` on the Mac, and if you are copying an image the formatting is unnecessary, as it gets totally overwritten - it just adds another write cycle to the card).

Comment: You real question is that you filled up your SD Card and can't boot. You may be able to fix this on a Linux system which can mount `ext4` partitions. Can you run the original 16 GB card on the PI?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the reverse problem of what I ran into the other day. As someone in the comments pointed out the problem might be that you cannot boot because the 16 GB partition you have written to the 64 GB SD card is filled.

The guide below is for reducing the size of a partition of an image to fit it on a smaller SD Card, you might want to try following the guide from "Resizing a partition within an image file" but try to increase the size of the partition instead.

http://www.aoakley.com/articles/2015-10-09-resizing-sd-images.php

Hope this helps?

P.S you might want to also look at this thread, they were having trouble using NOOBS on a high capacity card

[Formatting 64/128gb microSC card to run on RP3](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/57970/formatting-64-128gb-microsc-card-to-run-on-rp3)