# Formatting 64/128gb microSC card to run on RP3

Tags: pi-2, pi-3, sd-card, noobs, partition

I had no success with experimenting on my SanDisk Ultra 64GB microSDXC UHS-I (SDSQUNC-064G-GN6MA).

I tried formatting entire one to Fat, Fat32 using 3rd party software, making small Fat/Fat32 partition on PI3.

How can I make it work? What brands work with 64GB AND 128GB cards? and What partition strategies to use?

I need A LOT of disk space. What other strategies could I use?

I got PI 2, but also getting PI 3.

Solution. As author of accepted solution mentioned, the NOOBS will not run in my situation so I've installed a Rasbian directly, which solved my problem.

Comment: What have you tried? What OS are you using? How did you try to set it up? What happens when you try? All we know so far is that you have had little succeess.

Comment: latest noob/rasbien and windows 10. what else would u like to know? specifics please ?

Comment: I don't know what else I could do here. so this is as specific as i can get. OP

Comment: I think there is a demarcation in USB Flash memory devices at the 32GByte capacity - above that they have to be SDXC devices and according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital#SDXC) they MUST (at least as supplied) be formatted with the (Micro$oft IP) "exFat file system, the use of which is governed by a proprietary license"... according to that article a (Windows/MacOS) host device (reader/writer) may not accept alternative file-system formats on SDXC devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the risk of being accused of being anti NOOBS, which is poorly documented, it is supposed to be an easy installation method. It assumes a normal SD Card; I don't know what it really expects and has probably not been tested with 64GB.

I suggest you install Raspbian - this doesn't need the card to be formatted, and creates an image. I have not tried a 64GB, but see no reason why it wouldn't work.

To address the other part of your question, I use 16GB cards. When I need extra space I use an external 1TB HD, which I have formatted as `ext4`. You could use any other form of storage, a solid state drive or USB stick. You won't get spectacular speed, because all Pi I/O goes through the same controller.

Comment: As per my other comment above, the OPs card is bigger than 32GBytes and is thus an SDXC not a SDHX card.  His 'Doze system may not let him format it to anything other than exFAT (which is how it will be supplied as that FS is part of the SDXC specification) however this is patent encumbered by those keen supporters of Open Source Software, Micro$oft (__NOT__). It is thus not free for use in things like _Debian_-derived _Raspian_.

Comment: Ah! I have installed the Rasbian directly and it works just fine! I didn't anticipated NOOBS causing issues.

Answer (score 1):

Despite my other comments I think you can make it work.  Checking on the [ELinux RPi-SDCard](http://elinux.org/RPi_SD_cards) page it explicitly refers to the exact device mentioned and someone says "tested on Raspberry Pi 2" in December 2015.  Further more I refer you to this related question and the accepted answer: [Raspberry Pi 2 - Are 64GB UHS-I Class 1 SDXC cards supported?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/28571/raspberry-pi-2-are-64gb-uhs-i-class-1-sdxc-cards-supported)

Comment: Yes - BUT!  NOOBS is supposed to be **easier** for beginners. If you have to jump through hoops to install it, why not just bypass NOOBS and go straight to Raspbian.