# Trying to use second sd card raspberry pi

Tags: pi-4, noobs

I just got a new 64 GB micro sd card and installed NOOBS based off this tutorial (https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/noobs-install). I did not format it since I just bought the sd card and it had nothing previously on it. When I inserted it into my pi 4, the green light did not turn on, and there was no hdmi signal. I have prevously used a 32 GB micro sd card with NOOBS preinstalled to run Raspbian on this pi 4, but I wanted to try with this micro SD card. Why isn't this working?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Formatting 64/128gb microSC card to run on RP3](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/57970/formatting-64-128gb-microsc-card-to-run-on-rp3)

Comment: What software you used for installing the disk image?

Answer (score 4):

Because the SD Card is formatted as exFAT. It needs to be reformatted - BUT save yourself a lot of trouble and forget [NOOBS](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/92069/8697)
.

Install Raspbian using the Foundation installer.